# How can I save everything from console

Tags: r

I am a beginner working in r, how do you save everything from console, your commands, as well as the output, everything that appears in the console.

Only things that I could come up with is sink(...), before starting the session. i.e.

```
sink("dataout.txt")
```

but then nothing appears in the console everything(except plots) goes to dataout.txt file.  What I need is to be able to look at what I have done throughout any given session after dabbling around. 
thx

Comment: The console is for dabbling about. You can use `savehistory` to save the commands and `save.image` to save the objects created. The important analysis should be placed into a script. Often we use packages like `brew`, `rweave`, `knitr`, `pander`, etc. to create reproducible reports of our analysis.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `savehistory("dataout.txt")` which will write the entire history as plaintext.

Comment: Thanks.  How far does it go with savehistory()? Presumably to the last time one restarts R.

Comment: @BalsherSingh Correct. If you are looking to reload your history into R, you can also use the `.rhistory` extension instead of `.txt`. R doesn't really care which extension you use and both can be opened in a text editor, but using the .rhistory file can make it easier to find in the future.

Comment: savehistory() is good to know, but I need the output from R as well, especially when an error comes up.  thx

Comment: @BalsherSingh @BalsherSingh - Short answer? You can't. You'll need to start working with R scripts, using knitr, the IR kernel for Jupyter Notebooks, etc, and saving your output using. If you are using an R script you can do  `sink()` combined with `source('script.R', echo = TRUE)`. `source('script.R', echo = TRUE)` will print both the commands and the output to the console, but there isn't currently a way to do it line by line and have it print everything as go.