# Summary of error notifications from console

Tags: r, error-handling, summary

I am running a long R script. Is there a way to give me an overview of all the errors that occured after the script has run. (e.g. a function that I could enter after the script has finished running and that extracts me the error notifications from the console)

Comment: I'm not an expert in it, but you might try wrapping your function in the `safely` function from the `purrr` package. It should give you a list of return values and errors when you run a function.

Comment: also see `sink` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096989/how-to-save-all-console-output-to-file-in-r and `savehistory` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750173/how-can-i-save-everything-from-console

Comment: I will check those functions out, thanks for the help!